# Users can't even open app and app won't let user delete it

Tags: ios, app-store

Recently, We received more iOS App Store reviews about that Users can't even open app and app won't let user delete it, This is strange, where there is a problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand why your app crashes, you have to include some kind of crash Analytics code. (Crashlytics and Google Analytics have these feature.) On top of these, you can also check iTunesconnect for more information.

App not opening is an issue in your startup code. Check your code in these functions.

```
application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

App not allowing to delete, is not possible on iOS. There is no public API that lets you interfere with App deletion. So it might not be your code issue.